Self-adjoint unbounded Toeplitz operator
Let $M$ be a complete manifold and $E\to M$ a Dirac bundle (Hermitian vector bundle equipped with a Clifford action $c\colon T^*M\to \rm{End}(E)$ and a Clifford connection $\nabla$). The Dirac operator
$$D:=c\circ\nabla\colon \Gamma_c^{\infty}(E)\to L^2(E) $$
is an essentially self-adjoint operator. We denote its closure by $D\colon W^1(E)\to L^2(E)$, where $W^1(E)$ is the first Sobolev space on $E$. Let $\mathcal{H}:=\ker D\subset W^1(E)$ and $P\colon L^2(E)\to \mathcal{H}$ the orthogonal projection onto the kernel of $D$.
Let $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$ be a real function on $M$ and assume that $(f\pm i)^{-1}\in C_0(M)$ vanishes at infinity. We consider the unbounded multiplication operator
$$M_f\colon {\rm{Dom}}(M_f)\to L^2(E), $$
where ${\rm{Dom}}(M_f):=\{\psi\in L^2(E): f\psi\in L^2(E)\}$. It is straight-forward to show that $M_f$ is a self-adjoint operator. We define the Toeplitz operator associated with $f$ by
$$ T_f:= P\circ M_f\colon {\rm{Dom}}(M_f)\cap \mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}.$$
I would like to know if it is possible to prove that $T_f$ is (essentially?) self-adjoint in the unbounded case.
What I have tried so far
In order to prove that $M_f$ is self-adjoint, we simply use the fact that $(M_f\pm i)^{-1}$ defines a bounded operator on $L^2(E)$, since it is a bounded function. It follows that $M_f$ is a symmetric, densely-defined operator with $M_f\pm i$ a surjective operator. I wonder if a similar argument couldn't be performed with $T_f$, but the projection to the kernel there makes things much harder.
Solution under some additional assumptions
I am still not sure if the question can be answered as originally posed, but I found some assumptions under which we may prove self-adjointness of the operator $T_f$:

Zero is an isolated point in the spectrum of $D\colon W^1(E)\to L^2(E)$.
The function $f$ has bounded derivatives.

Assumption 1 allow us to write the projection $P$ using holomorphic calculus: let $B\subset\mathbb{C}$ be an open ball around $0$ not intersecting any other element of the spectrum of $D$. Then
$$P=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B}(\lambda -D)^{-1}\,d\lambda. $$
This projection is also called a Riesz projection. The idea is then to calculate
$$[P,M_f]=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B}(\lambda-D)^{-1}c(df)(\lambda-D)^{-1}\,d\lambda,$$
which extends to a bounded operator on $L^2(E)$, by assumption 2. The fact that $T_f$ is self-adjoint then follows from Proposition 3.5 in here, which is a result on Hilbert $C^*$-modules.
These additional assumptions are quite natural in my setting, so this answer will suffice. I will leave the bounty on for anyone who can prove this assertion without the additional assumptions, or provide with a counter-example.
